# Referring question of the phrase " in this respect" in the following sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns, attachment-ambiguity

> For the activity of being aware is one of those, like chess **in this
> respect**, where understanding their point is itself part of their
> point.

It's seem like the phrase "**in this respect**" always refers to something that mentioned before, but I am here to ask that if there any possible for the phrase "**in this respect**" refers to something mentioned after the phrase, which in my example is "**where understanding their point is itself part of their point**".

And I have two more question about this sentence. It's obvious that the relative pronoun "where" isn't refers to any exact places, I am wondering that if it is a grammatically error. If it isn't, then how should I understand the use of the word "where" in this sentence?

This is the paragraph where the sentence came from(in case anyone need some context):

> Thus we can’t just say: whoever is aware must know the basic conditions of failure, in the
> sense of having already accepted some formulation of them. But we can say that we must be able
> to recognize these as conditions of failure. For the activity of being aware is one of those, like
> chess in this respect, where understanding their point is itself part of their point. That is, if I
> couldn’t recognize that, when all broke down into confusion, awareness had failed, then you
> couldn’t think of me as aware in the first place. We aren’t aware at all unless we can recognize this
> difference.

Comment: Is this paragraph actually written by an English speaker? It's incomprehensible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman no, it's written by a social scientist ;-)

Comment: The paragraph came from a book named Philosophical Arguments written by Charles Taylor. 

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to over think this.  "In this respect" is referring to the entire sentence which is talking about  "the activity ... where [something happens]".  The author mentions chess as a comparison/analogy. If you remove the part about chess within the commas, the sentence still makes sense.

One could reword this by simply using "like in chess".  The use of "in this respect" could be said to be superfluous here, since it is obvious from the context.

As to the second part of your question, the pronoun "where" doesn't always refer to a literal physical place, it can also be synonymous with "in which", depending on context.  If you check any good dictionary, you will see the word has multiple definitions. In the OED, the word "where" has at least 28 definitions!

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. So I can say that if I understand in the way as you do, the chess is just simply an example of "one of those"?

Comment: @caolizhibai - yes absolutely, it is one of those activities.